# Spring, annotation based, overriding of components

Tags: java, spring

When I setup Spring with XML a can override component definitions in XML files that are loaded later.
It's very usefull for tests - I create default config set and than load it with addition test configuration that replaces some of components with specials (stubs, mocks, and so on).
Now i start to migrate to annotation based configurations and it causes some problems.

The direct way to use annotations is auto-discovering of packages with @Component

So I have

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"some.pack1", "some.pack2"})
public class ProductConfig{}
```

And when
    @Configuration
    @Import({ProductConfig.class})
    @ComponentScan({"test.pack"})
    public class TestConfig{}

But it will cause conflict if I try to override components in test.pack

And what I can do?

After some investigations where are 3 answers with some issues on them

1. Worst - i can use @Filter on ComponentScan - it's worst way,

   - i must not import existed config (that can has some additional beans)
   - i must rescan all components, and explicitly define set of filters
2. i can use @Profile and activeProfiles - it's better, while it's more sophistical, implict, but

   - it means that i must to know at product classes that they can be disabled in some tests
3. not to use @ComponentScan on override Config and using @Bean insted of it

   - it's maybe well on test configurations, but it means that I lost ability to use @Component annotation
4. use setParent on contexts - it works well, but

   - it's explicit operation on implementation of ApplicationContext not on interface
   - it's not hard to setup if overriding services has @Autwire dependency on some components from overriden config - require manual register and refresh

What is best and standard way to override conigurations??? When I used XML-based it was not a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@profile plays a crucial role while implementing the testing strategy for your service/code.

For example, in development, you may have:

```
public interface DataSource{
 public String getHost();
}
```

Default implementation is

```
@Component
@Profile("Prod") 
public class DevDataSource implements DataSource {
    public String getHost(){
     // return actual value
}
```

And the implementation for component tests(Fake impl)

```
@Component
@Profile("test") 
public class StubbyDataSource implements DataSource {
    public String getHost(){
     return "some-host";   // return mocked data
}
```

Now you can write a test here which can act as *integration test*, *unit test* and *component tests* (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ComponentTest.html)

In that way, your testing strategy would be much more elegant, concise and easy to maintain. *Just by changing the profile*, the same test can point to different environments (real or fake).